# Robotframework wait until page is fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I would like to automate a log in process in Robotframework. Unfortunately I don't know that the current user has a soft token or not. If the user doesn't have any, will get an SMS immediately. If the user has one or more soft tokens, he/she has to click on a link, to get the SMS.

The process:
[the login process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRlHc.png)

The code:

```
Input Text  ${userNameField}  ${User}
Click element  ${nextButton}

${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   ${getSMSCodeButton}
Run Keyword If    ${present}    Click element   ${getSMSCodeButton}
Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${passwordField}
Input Text  ${passwordField}  Password1
```

The main problem, after I click on the next button, the ${present} variable will be always False, because the next page doesn't loaded yet. If I add some implicit wait (3 sec) after "Click element  ${nextButton}", the code works like charm, but I don't want to use the Sleep keyword, rather I would like to wait for to load the page fully.

How should I solve it, with explicit wait?

Answer (score 0):

You can control better the implicit wait and timeouts when importing the library. See the section [Importing](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Importing).

But by replacing `Element Should Be Visible` by `[Wait Until Element is Visible][2]` you will get what you need. Below is you test code, using new recommended `IF`:

```
*** Settings ***
Library      SeleniumLibrary    15    5

(...)

Input Text  ${userNameField}  ${User}
Click element  ${nextButton}

${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Wait Until Element Is Visible 
   ${getSMSCodeButton}
IF    ${present}
    Click Element   ${getSMSCodeButton}
END
Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${passwordField}
Input Text  ${passwordField}  Password1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is alternate kw present too, try to use Waits until the element locator appears on the current page.

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element <locator>
```